# Exchange Server Clone unable to login

Tags: exchange, acronis

I am currently undergoing a site upgrade and I haven't yet got to the Exchange Server 2003, however, there is construction next door and long story short, there were several outages (yes servers are on UPS) and one lasted for a while and the exchange box went offline and now won't boot.

A few hours later I realized disks were damaged. I replaced the disks and performed a image restore using Acronis. The image was restored without errors, but when I try to logon I get the message

> Windows cannot connect to the domain, either because the domain
>   controller is down or otherwise unavailable, or because your computer
>   account was not found. Please try again later. If this message
>   continues to appear, contact your system administrator for assistance.

<del>Is it possible to dis-join this Exchange Server from the domain and then rejoin to fix this error?</del>

Edit: The post was down-voted, not sure why.

Let me correct the question:

Would dis-joining/re-joining an exchange server to a domain cause a problem? It seems to be the only way to fix the problem above.

Comment: Have you verified that a DC is available?

Comment: Yes I did. There are two DCs and both online.

Comment: The acronis image was how much old ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you disable all Exchange servers, then do the remove from the domain add to the domain steps, it can work. Once it is back in the domain, change the services back to automatic/manual then restart the server.

Whether it will work correctly though is a different matter. Exchange is not suited to image based backup because of the extensive interaction with the domain.

The best way forward would be to DR install Exchange on a fresh build of Windows, then restore the databases from the backup.

Of course... Exchange 2010 with a DAG would have avoided this issue. Exchange 2003 is well past its sell by date.